# Specifiy Response charset for CRUD-API

Tags: character-encoding, content-type, orbeon

I access the endpoint "/fr/service/persistence/crud/$app/$form/form.xhtml" using the built-in tools of DB2:

```
values systools.HTTPGETCLOB('https://.../fr/service/persistence/crud/$app/$form/form.xhtml', '<httpHeader><header name ="accept" value="application/xml; charset=utf-8"/><header name ="Orbeon-Form-Definition-Version" value="1"/></httpHeader>');
```

The data is stored in a PostgreSQL database which is encoded in utf-8.
My problem is that the umlauts are not displayed correctly, because DB2 insists that the charset is also specified in the content type. However, Orbeon only returns "application/xml" as the Content-Type.
I have created a mock server that specifies Content-Type plus charset and then DB2 has no problems with correctly displaying the umlauts.

Is there a way to configure Orbeon to include the charset with the Content-Type?

Additional Information:

- Tomcat 9.0.50

Any guidance and assistance is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to specify that, sorry.

`application/xml` does not require a `charset` parameter, as the XML document itself can specify a character encoding, and XML defaults to UTF-8 if nothing else is available anyway. So I am not even sure it would be a good idea to pass a `charset` parameter in addition, although it probably wouldn't hurt. But again, this is not configurable at the moment so you'll have to find a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wrote a Wrapper-API to add the charset parameter to the content-type parameter and it works fine now.